# pytest command line argument failing

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pytest

I have added conftest.py at the same directory level as my test file . The content of my conftest.py :

```
 import pytest

    def pytest_addoption(parser):
        parser.addoption("--l", action="store", help="Get license value")
    @pytest.fixture
    def lic(request):
        return request.config.getoption("--l")
```

and following is my test file def

```
   def  test(lic):
        print "testing license : %s"%lic
        assert 0
```

But i still get following error:

```
   pytest  .\source\test_latestLinuxAgent.py --l=test
        pytest : usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
        At line:1 char:1
        + pytest  .\source\test_latestLinuxAgent.py --l=test


        pytest: error: ambiguous option: --l=test could match --lf, --last-failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the response says, `--l` option is ambiguous. What does it mean?

Let me explain it with an example. If you have `--zaaaa` option, the shortcut for it is `--z`. However, there is one condition: `--zaaaa` must be the only option starting with `z` char. Otherwise, the interpreter does not know which option should be chosen.

You can't define `--l` option because there are two options starting with `l` char: `--lf` and `--last-failed`.

I suggest creating non-conflicting option, `--license` would be nice.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue !